# Building Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project: “ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project”

Tags: installation

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to solving this issue. I have found numerous workarounds and even a hot fix by using Google, however none of it solves the problem. I am at a loss of what to do.

I have tried this Hotfix: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30681

I have tried clearing the Hierarchy/File contents in the .vdproj file

I have tried the suggestion listed at this blog: http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/building-visual-studio-2010-setup-project-error-unable-to-update-the-dependencies-of-the-project/

I have tried dumping that .vdproj from the solution altogether and creating a new one. This one will build, but when I try deploying, I get a new problem that I can't find a solution for. (The application will not install as a service, which it should). I want to get the original set up project working to see if it will install correctly.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround that I have not listed above? Alternatively, can anyone tell me what would cause a setup project to not deploy as a service as it is intended to be? I have done this with other services in the past, and it just worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve it using the following KB article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169

Answer (score 1):

1-Remove the Installer project from your solution through the IDE interface
2-Add the Installer project back into your solution (Add > Existing Project...)
3-Rebuild
It works practically every time for me...